Is it a valid request to a professor to delay other tasks till I decide on my PhD topic?
I have been working with my professor for a project for last 1 year. Initially he was excited to work with me, but recently I noticed, whenever I try to discuss my approaches to him, he avoids, making different excuses. I guess I couldn't come up with an approach good enough to take his time. (Needless to say, I have not published any paper yet.)
Also, I took my PhD entrance exam and took admission to my institute (same institute where I was doing a project) recently. Because I have been working with the prof, I assumed I will be doing PhD under him, as he discussed 1 year back. He has also started giving me teaching assistant responsibilities for his classes.
But sensing his disinterest (though he didn't tell me anything upfront), I asked him about the plan for my PhD and any feedback on my performance. He delayed the discussion for a few days, then told me that he will retire soon and I might take a few years for completing my PhD, so I might want to find a younger professor. Next day I asked another professor, and he was ready to guide me. So I informed the same to my current professor.
I am also facing issue with a student under my current professor, who seems to be jealous on me getting professor's attention, or professor giving me respect, as I am older to the other students. The student has submitted his thesis and will obtain his PhD in a year. He keeps on making a lot of sound in the lab, whenever he sees me doing something with full concentration. He also does things to irritate me, like opening the drawer beside my desk and never closing. He also hits my chair repeatedly with an excuse as if he is doing something. (he sits just behind me). He also has a habit of misbehaving with me. So, I just try to ignore and avoid him, so I can concentrate on my work, and don't spend all time thinking about how irritating he is.
Since the professor is anyways not going to be my guide, I asked professor, if I can concentrate on my courses and find my PhD topic for the time being, and sit in the lab of the new professor, under which I will be doing my Phd, and once some topic is finalised, I will get back to his lab and restart any pending work, or other teaching responsibilities.
My old professor did not reply to my email. Which means I guess, he is not fine with it.
Is it not a legitimate request for a PhD student to get settled a bit, and finalise a topic, before getting distracted to so many other tasks?
My batchmates, other PhD entries, are all attending courses and deciding about their profs. I do not think any of them have started with teaching assistantship yet. It has been only 3 months after entrance to this course.

There is far too much here that is unrelated to the headline question. It reads mostly like a rant, actually. Can you reduce it to the essential question?

No, I am not ranting. I have friends to rant. I have given all details so the full situation is clear. I am asking for advice on my next step. With no reply, is it ok that I start working with my new advisor for my PhD topic? Or do I meet the other professor personally and ask for permission again?

It looks like you are covering at least three different topics here: The disinterest of your first professor and moving to another, the issue with a student under your current professor, and whether settling in before the brunt of the PhD work is legitimate. Please focus on one, or at least make it clear how they relate to each other.

FWIW, I am somewhat confused by the timeline you suggest. If I am reading this right, you want to move to Professor New's lab now before you have a topic to work on there; once you have a topic with Professor New, you want to move back to Professor Old to finish your obligations there. Why not finish your old obligations before you have something new to work on?

@MisterMiyagi, that makes sense. I am fine with completing old things, but I am getting new workload. Whatever teaching responsibility the jealous student is denying to perform and asking to assign to me, prof is assigning them to me. Also I used to mentor some junior project people when they came new here, those people are calling and demanding me to be in the laboratory to still guide them saying they got a lot of work. I don't want to perform these extra additions. These people do not know though that I am no more under prof.

@MadamCurie Sorry, I don’t understand how that is supposed to answer my comment. Did I get the planned timeline right? Is there a reason for not doing it the other way around?

Is it possible that your current professor has some health or other personal problems and may have difficulties to concentrate, and consequently to give you proper supervision? (I have experience with a supervisor and another close professor in such situations.) Also could it be that he doesn't retire because of reaching the standard age but early, and that maybe he has decided this only recently based on health or other issues? I can imagine the reason for his behaviour may be different from not appreciating your work.

Who funds you and for what???

As @Buffy notes, who is paying you? Would you be OK if your current professor stopped paying you since you were busy with other things?

Payment is not professor dependent. It is from the institute.

All of these issues sound like they could be improved if you communicated more directly (but of course not angrily).
For instance, you deal with an annoying peer by saying, “Dude! What the heck! Do you realize you keep bumping my chair? What’s up with that?” Or “Hey man, it seems like you are annoyed with me. Am I reading you right?”
You should ask complicated questions to your advisor in person. Yes, you can likely ask for fewer TA responsibilities if it is not part of your contract.
You should directly tell students from your last job that they need to stand on their own two feet. Maybe give them a little pep talk about how they are ready to do so.

Accepting the answer. However it does not work with the peer. I have tried reasoning out with him once. He started fighting, behaved as if he is very upset on me, stopped talking to me for 2 weeks, until he got a teaching assignment and had to work with me. He also tried to isolate me from other peers. Told (I don't know what) to all other peers around, so people were coming to talk to me when he is not around, and as soon as he enters the lab, people became serious, and moved back to desk).

He is a passive aggressive bully. When he sees I am good with others, all of a sudden he starts behaving very nicely and try to be my friend, and as soon as he sees I have started talking to him normally, he starts misbehaving. And his misbehaves are increasing with time. Earlier he used to keep normal distance. Nowadays he got so desperate that started physically hitting my chair!

I tried changing my sitting place (as my PC had a problem), looks like he is unhappy. He made all efforts so I get back to my seat behind him. Recently I couldn't go to the lab for some time due to health issue (with permission from professor). Yesterday went to the institute after a few weeks. That peer saw me on road, and forcefully came behind me to speak to me, though I was trying to avoid him. He behaved initially like a gentleman. Enquired what problem I have. Then told me another peer is coming to the lab and coughing like me. Also told me I should not attend courses, and sit in lab.

Looks like he wants me to sit beside him at any cost, and keep troubling me :)

In fact the main reason why I want to move to the other laboratory is because I am unable to concentrate on my work in this lab, this peer disturbing me all the time. I think the professor also understands it to some extent. Yesterday I spoke with him, and he gave me permission to concentrate on courses and PhD topic now, and coming to lab at later point.
